# JS Charts: drawing trend lines

Tags: javascript, charts

IVe been trying to use http://www.jscharts.com/ (JS Charts) for plotting stock market stats. But I was wondering if JS charts has an option to add pattern lines or trend lines in order to mark down the daily patterns or trend of the graph. I want to know if JS Charts provides that option or is there any other javascript charts that provides this option?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this in fusion charts using line graph or using simple bar graph in combination with trend line showing the pattern.

here is the demo:

http://www.fusioncharts.com/demos/business/management-dashboard/view/

https://www.ourrelationship.com/mod/mcfeedback/Fusion/Contents/ChartSS/XML_MSLine2D.html

And if you are using JScharts you can use there Line-Carts plugin to show trend lines.

heres there demo link:

http://www.jscharts.com/examples#line-charts

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks...But I am looking to do the trend analysis on line graphs.. Is that option available in fusionCharts?

Answer (score 0):

You could use jsChart's [Line Charts](http://www.jscharts.com/how-to-use-line-graphs) for adding trending lines.
Of if you can use jQuery, then see this link: [jQPlot](http://www.jqplot.com/)

Comment: Is the option to add trend lines available in jqplot??